# How do I lock iPhone 5 in landscape mode?

Tags: ios, iphone

How do I lock iPhone 5 in landscape mode? I see how to lock it in portrait mode, and I've tried locking it in landscape mode using the assistive touch feature, but that isn't working for me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apparently you can!

If you want to try this out for yourself, here is the navigation to get to the setting:

1. Enabling AssistiveTouch:
2. Settings App>General>Scroll Down to Accessibility>Scroll Down to AssistiveTouch '
3. Toggle on AssistiveTouch.

Switching to Landscape:

1. Lock the device in portrait mode
2. Press Floating Square>Device>Rotate Screen>Left/Right

http://www.todaysiphone.com/2011/10/tips-tricks-lock-iphone-orientation-in-landscape/ ......................

Comment: Doesn't help too much because you still have to do this over again after lock/unlock... I hate that iBooks constantly keeps turning the page to portrait. Totally unsuitable for pdf reading.

Comment: @level1807, Apple seriously needs more folks in the usability design team, not just visual design.

Comment: Note that this hack doesn't work for iPhone 6S

Answer (score 4):

You cannot. The iPhone is not like the iPad, which truly and fully supports the two modes (even SpringBoard rotates). The iPhone doesn't technically have a true landscape mode. At best, most apps support the orientation but that's as far as it goes. Rotation Lock on the iPhone locks the device in portrait mode. You can test this yourself by going into Mail, turning the device sideways (landscape) and then engaging the orientation lock. You'll see that Mail will orient to portrait.

Comment: This has always irked me greatly. It wouldn't be that hard to lock whatever orientation the user is currently utilizing.

Comment: @ChrisA, I don't get what's so hard about this too. It would be easy for Apple to simply disable the "rotate" event to all apps, then apps woudln't rotate since they would still be thinking the iPhone is in portrait mode.

Answer (score 4):

As the other people have said, it is impossible to truly lock your phone in landscape mode. I do not know exactly why you want to do that, but I'm going to guess it is so that the screen does not flip back to the standard orientation when you are trying to read or watch something while lying down your side.

If that is the case, there is another solution: Orient the phone so that it is perpendicular to the ground until it jumps into landscape mode, then simply turn the phone so that the home button is at the top and the camera is on the bottom. The screen should remain in landscape mode and you may browse in comfort.

If my guess was off, perhaps you could further explain why you'd like to lock the phone in a landscape position and perhaps there is an alternative means to your intended result.

Comment: Thanks! I don't recall why. It may have had to do with delivering presentations with Prezi and wanting to keep it in landscape mode the entire presentation. Otherwise your guess is as good as mine. :)